# Play Store | Can't update new release to remove the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, android-app-bundle

Google notify me that my app use the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. I removed it and I tried to upload a new .aab, but I can't save the new releases (Production or Internal testing).

The current .aab in active for two releases:

[image: Current .aab releases]

I created a new release on Internal testing but I can't save

[image: internal testing]

[image: can't save]

These are the permissions of the new .aab
[image: permission]

I did the same things in the production channel, same problem. What can I do?